# Keystone JS 0.3.22 - Admin UI slow load + eventual timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I'm currently having an issue with my install of keystone. The admin UI is running incredibly slowly. I've had a dig around in the console and certain files are holding up the browser rendering. So far files I've noticed are:

- /keystone/js/home.js
- /keystone/js/fields.js
- /keystone/js/item.js

Sometimes these files load - it takes a very long time. Other times the load of these files times out leaving a blank admin page.

My version of keystone is 0.3.22 any ideas on a fix?

Thanks

Dylan

Comment: I don't have this problem on the same Keystone version. Have you tried this on another machine? Do you have lots of data that those files need to load? They normally take a while to load once and never again during that session.